# How to specify alternative response formats with swagger/OpenAPI?

Tags: format, swagger

I have a [`swagger.yaml`](http://swagger.io/) something like this:

```
swagger: "2.0"
paths:
  /something:
    get:
      parameters:
        - name: format
          in: query
          type: string
          pattern: '^(csv|json|xml)$'
      responses:
        200:
          schema:
            type: ?
```

And I want to return different formats (csv, json, xml) depending on the value of the `format` query parameter (eg. localhost/api/something?format=csv).

How can I specify the different response formats in the spec?

Comment: After further investigation, I think the only solution is to use different endpoints for the different formats, instead of a parameter. (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/146 gives an example). Is that right?

Comment: Actually I'm not even sure this works in connexion... specifying two different "produces" seems to lead to a `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable` error.

Answer (score 6):

I found a workaround, by providing different endpoints:

```
swagger: "2.0"
paths:
  /something/json:
    get:
      produces:
        - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              ...
  /something/csv:
    get:
      produces:
        - text/csv
      responses:
        200:
          schema:
            type: string
```

Note the different `produces:` inside each `get`, and none at the top level.

The actual response header for the csv endpoint is:

```
Content-Length:64
Content-Type:text/csv; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 26 Aug 2016
```

I have also tried adding headers to the yaml (straight after the code above), but it doesn't change the actual response header:

```
          headers:
            Content-type:
              type: string
              description: text/csv; charset=utf-8
            Content-Disposition:
              type: string
              description: attachment; filename=data.csv
```

At either endpoint I get a console message (I am building this using [connexion](http://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)):

`Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json`, or

`Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/csv`

Also, the csv is interpreted as a file to download, not displayed in the browser.

...so I suspect I haven't quite got it right yet.